# Failed to compile. Syntax Error: Unexpected token in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm having a hard time solving this issue. I got a error saying
Syntax Error: Unexpected token

issue:
Syntax Error: Unexpected token (5:14)

```
export default createStore({
     state: {
     isLoading = false,
                   ^
       isAuthenticated = false,
       token: ''
     },
```

this is my package.json

```
{


 "name": "vdjcrm_vue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bulma": "^0.9.2",
    "bulma-toast": "^2.3.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the documentation for vuex 4.0 you can see that you are using `createStore` incorrectly (assuming that you are using ES2015 syntax). `state` should be a function returning your initial store state. Furthermore your syntax for the object properties is wrong. You need to use `:` instead of `=`.

So your code should be:

```
export default createStore({
     state () {
        return {
          isLoading: false,
          isAuthenticated: false,
          token: ''
        }
     }
})
```

Source: https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store